# preg_grep with html source

Tags: php, expression, preg-grep

I want extract this line

```html
<p>@include{"portal.shared.blook"}</p>
```

using

```php
preg_grep("/(\s*@include.*)/",explode("\n", $Source))
```

from this source code

```html
<html>
   <head>
        <title>hi</title>
   </head>
   <body>
        <h1>Hi I am layout</h1>
        <br>
        <p>@include{"portal.shared.blook"}</p>
        @require{"portal.shared.footer":"[main]"}
```

Some times the code has whitespace and I can not handle it

Comment: Will this line be same always like this? `<p>@include{"Some Text here"}</p>`

Comment: yes but "some text here" chanage

Comment: Whitespace can be represented by the character `\s`

Comment: i reach this preg_grep('/(@include{"(.*)"}*)/',explode("\n", $Source)
but still show me the <p> tag

Comment: You could do something like this afterwards: `preg_replace('/<p>/', '', preg_replace('/</p>/', '', $string));`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?<=\<\w\>)(\s*@include.*)(?=\<\/\w\>)
```

Working example:
https://regex101.com/r/wM1lB8/2

Comment: I reach this  "(@include{"(.*)"}*)" its oky on online tester but locally in php still has <p> attached

Comment: How are you using it in the PHP code? can you post it?

Comment: sure , $Source is html file
 foreach(preg_match('/(@include{"(.*)"}*)/', $Source) as $Tempstring)
                {
                    print_r( $Tempstring);
                }

Comment: preg_match returns an int. You shouldn't use this way. You can do something like: `preg_match('/(?<=\<\w\>)(\s*@include.*)(?=\<\/\w\>)/', $Source, $matches);` then iterate over `$matches`